# Source button missing from hibernate configuration XML file in eclipse

Tags: java, hibernate

When I created a hibernate Configuration file, eclipse is not able to display the source code as there is no source button at the bottom of the page. I can able to navigate between Session Factory and Security whereas Source button is missing. How can fix this issue? I have attached the picture below for reference.
  [Hibernate Configuration XML File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLvB2.png)

Comment: can you please rephrase the question to understand what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: and I will suggest you from the next time, to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

make your own one and add the below:

fileName is: `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Book</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <mapping resource="book.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And if you want to read more about it go [here](https://mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-load-hibernate-cfg-xml-from-different-directory/)